# Logical suite and inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

This is a related problem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340586/how-to-find-this-minimum-of-the-value/2354712?noredirect=1#comment4875481_2354712))

We have the following inequalities :

> For $n=3$ with $a,b,c$ real numbers the following inequality holds.
>   $$\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(c-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(a-c)^2}+(c-b)^2+(c-a)^2+(a-b)^2\geq \sqrt{54}$$

For $n=4$ with $a,b,c,d$ real numbers

$$\frac{1}{(a-d)^2}+\frac{1}{(d-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(d-c)^2}+\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(c-b)^2}+\frac{1}{(a-c)^2}+(d-b)^2+(c-d)^2+(a-d)^2+(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(a-c)^2\geq \sqrt{288}$$

If we continue with $n=5,6,7\cdots$ there is a logical suite but I don't know how to prove this and what is the following numbers .
Thanks.

Comment: what is the case for $n=2$?

Comment: what is the logic for $54=2\cdot 3^3$ and $288=2^5\cdot 3^2$?

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner for the case $n=2$ the minimum is 2 . Arnaldo I don't know what is the general logic behind this ...

Comment: By solving a horrible set of self consistent equations, I find RHS$_5 = \sqrt{1000}$. Simulation for $n$ up to $10$ suggest $$\text{RHS}_{n=2,3,\ldots,10}  = (\sqrt{4},\sqrt{54},\sqrt{288},\sqrt{1000},\sqrt{2700},\sqrt{6174},\sqrt{12544},\sqrt{23328},\sqrt{40500})$$ This has the form $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}$ for generic $n$.

Comment: @achille hui you have made a good work thanks for that . What do you suggest for a proof ? Can we use convexity ? I have a last question can we use Bernoulli's numbers for a general case with a $k$ power ?

Comment: @max8128, I don't think convexity is enough b/c the minimum is achieved at configuration that doesn't look that simple. Up to an overall offset, the minimum seems to be achieved at roots of $H_n(\sqrt[4]{2n}x)$ where $H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2} = \left(2x-\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \cdot 1$ is the physicist's [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) of order $n$.

Comment: BTW, for general $n$, the minimum value is given by formula in previous comment. It can be obtained as the classical limit of ground state energy of an exactly solvable quantum $N$-body problem (harmonic rational Calogero model). I'm still looking for a classical proof for this. No idea for the general $k$ power

Comment: @achillehui maybe for the general case we can consider the Dickson polynomial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson_polynomial .Have you nice idea on this ?

Comment: @max8128 At first glance, there doesn't seem to be any relation between Dickson polynomial and this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, let
$$\Delta_\alpha(x) = \sum\limits_{1\le i < j\le n}(x_i - x_j)^\alpha$$ 
For functions other that $\Delta_\alpha(x)$ and coordinate indices $x_k$, we will use subscript to denote first order partial derivatives. i.e. for all other function $p(x)$, 
$$p_k(x) \stackrel{def}{=} (\partial_k p)(x) \stackrel{def}{=}\frac{\partial p(x)}{\partial x_k}$$

The question at hand can be rephrased as:

> When $x$ varies over $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is the minimum value of the function 
>   $$U(x) = \Delta_2(x) + \Delta_{-2}(x)$$

Since $U(x)$ is invariant under translation, it is easy to see the minimum value of $U(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ equals to the minimum value of another function
$$V(x) = U(x) + \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^2 = n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 + \Delta_{-2}(x)$$
Let $M_n$ be the common minumum value of these two functions. I'm going to
show for $n > 1$,
$$M_n \stackrel{def}{=} \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} U(x) = \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} V(x) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}$$

Let $X \subset C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ be the collection of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support such that for some $\delta > 0$, the function vanishes identically whenever any $|x_i - x_j| < \delta$.
For any normalized $f \in X$, i.e. $\int f^2 dx = 1$, let $\Lambda(f)$ be following quadratic functional:
$$\Lambda(f) \stackrel{def}{=}
\int \left[ \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac12 f_k^2 + \frac12\omega^2x_k^2 f^2 \right) + g^2\Delta_{-2} f^2 \right] dx\tag{*1}
$$
where $\omega, g > 0$ are parameters to be modified. Define two auxillary functions

$$\phi(x) = \sum_{1\le i < j \le n}\log|x_i - x_j|
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\Phi(x) = -\frac{\omega}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 + \lambda \phi(x)
$$
where $\lambda$ is another parameter to be fixed later.

Since $f(x)$ vanishes whenever any $|x_i-x_j|$ is sufficiently small, 
$h = f e^{-\Phi}$ also belongs to $X$.
In terms of $h$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\Lambda(f) 
&=
\int \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac12\left(h_k+ \Phi_k h\right)^2 + \frac12\omega^2x_k^2 h^2 \right] + g^2\Delta_{-2} h^2 \right\} e^{2\Phi} dx\\
&=
\int \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac12 h_k^2 + h_k \Phi_k h + \frac12( \omega^2x_k^2 + \Phi_k^2) h^2 \right] + g^2\Delta_{-2} h^2 \right\} e^{2\Phi} dx\\
&=
\int \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac12 h_k^2 - \frac{h^2}{2} e^{-2\Phi}\partial_k( e^{2\Phi} \Phi_k ) + \frac{h^2}{2}( \omega^2x_k^2 + \Phi_k^2)\right] + g^2\Delta_{-2} h^2 \right\} e^{2\Phi} dx\\
&=
\int \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac12 h_k^2 - \frac{h^2}{2} \partial_k( \Phi_k ) + \frac{h^2}{2}( \omega^2x_k^2 - \Phi_k^2) \right] + g^2\Delta_{-2} h^2 \right\} e^{2\Phi} dx
\end{align}
$$
Using following algebraic identities

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (\partial_k \phi)^2 = -\sum_{k=1}^n \partial_k^2 \phi = 2\Delta_{-2}\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k (\partial_k \phi) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
We find
$$\begin{align}
-\sum_{k=1}^n(\partial_k \Phi_k) 
&= \omega n - \lambda \sum_{k=1}^n\partial_k^2\phi = \omega n + 2\lambda \Delta_{-2}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\omega^2 x_k^2 - \Phi_k^2\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda\phi_k(2\omega x_k - \lambda \phi_k)
= \lambda\omega n(n-1) - 2\lambda^2 \Delta_{-2}
\end{align}
$$

When $g^2 = \lambda(\lambda - 1) \iff \lambda = \frac12\left(1+\sqrt{1+4g^2}\right)$, the $\Delta_{-2}$ terms cancelled out.
Above mess simplifies to

$$\Lambda(f) 
= \int \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac12 h_k^2 + \frac{h^2}{2} (\omega n + \lambda \omega n(n-1))\right]\right\} e^{2\Phi} dx
\ge \frac{\omega n}{2}\left( 1 + \lambda(n-1)\right)
$$
Set $\omega = \sqrt{2n}L$ and $g = L$ and send $L$ to $+\infty$, we obtain:

$$\begin{align}\int V(x)f(x)^2 dx 
= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{\Lambda(f)}{L^2}
&\ge \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n}n}{2L}\left( 1 + \frac12\left(1+\sqrt{1+4L^2}\right)(n-1)\right)\\
&= \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}
\end{align}
$$
For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose a $f$ such that $f(x)$ vanishes whenever $V(x) \ge M_n + \epsilon$, we find

$$M_n + \epsilon \ge \int V(x) f(x)^2 dx \ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}$$

Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrary small, we can deduce

$$M_n = \inf_{\epsilon > 0}( M_n + \epsilon )\ge\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}$$

For the other direction, restrict $L$ to even integers. We find $$e^\Phi = \left(e^{-\sqrt{2n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2 }\prod_{1\le i < j\le n}(x_i-x_j)^2\right)^\ell \quad\text{ where }\quad L = 2\ell$$
This is a smooth function over $\mathbb{R}^n$ which decay to $0$ rapidly as $|x| \to \infty$. Extending definition of the quadratic functional to these sort of function. If one pick a constant $K$ such that $\tilde{f} = K e^\Phi$ is normalized and repeat above derivations, we find

$$
\int \left[  \frac{1}{2L^2} \sum_{k=1}^n\tilde{f}_k^2 + V(x)\tilde{f}^2 \right] dx
=
\frac{\Lambda(\tilde{f})}{L^2}
= \frac{\omega n}{2L^2}(1 + \lambda(n-1))
$$
Since LHS is  bounded from below by $M_n$, we have
$$M_n \le \lim_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{\omega n}{2L^2}(1 + \lambda(n-1)) = 
\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}$$

Combine these, we can conclude

$$
\bbox[border:1px solid blue,1em]{
M_n 
= \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} U(x) 
= \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} V(x) 
= \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}\;\;
}
$$

---

**Notes**

1. Above proof is inspired by quantum mechanics.

   In $1971$, F. Calogero published a paper about a quantum one-dimensional $N$-body system.

   > F. Calogero, *Solution of the One‐Dimensional N‐Body Problems with Quadratic and/or Inversely Quadratic Pair Potentials*,
   >   Journal of Mathematical Physics 12, 419 (1971)

   The Hamiltonian of the system has the form:
   $$
   H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}
   + \sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\left\{
   \frac14 m\omega^2(x_i-x_j)^2+g(x_i-x_j)^{-2}\right\}
   $$
   He found the model is exactly solvable with energy levels given by following formula:
   $$E_{2n+k} = \hbar\omega\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\left[
   \frac12(N-1)+\frac12 N(N-1)(a+\frac12) + 2n+k
   \right]$$
   where $n = 0,1,2,\ldots, k = 0,1,2,\ldots$ and $a = \frac12\sqrt{1 + 4mg\hbar^{-2}}$.
   If one set $m = g = 1, \omega = 2$ and take the classical limit (i.e. $\hbar \to 0$), the ground state energy of the system will converge to the minimum of the potential $U(x)$. At the end, one will find $M_N  = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}\sqrt{2N}$.
2. Another interesting question is what configurations minimizes $V(x)$.

   When I'm doing an literature search on this topics, I come across a statement
   that minimum of $V(x)$ is achieved at positions proportional to the roots of Hermite polynomials. I cannot find the exact expression of $x_i$ which minimizes $V(x)$. However, by matching the roots of Hermite polynomials and results from my simulation, $V(x)$ should be minimized at roots of $H_n(\sqrt[4]{2n}x)$ where 
   $$H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2} = \left(2x-\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \cdot 1$$
   is the physicist's [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) of order $n$.

   Look at Héhéhé's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2373852/59379) for a proof of this interesting fact.

Comment: Wow It's incredible that far exceeds my level in mathematics .I would like to react as a poet and say like Baudelaire in a poem "A whole distant world" "... And in this strange and symbolic nature" .For me it's an enigmatic thing to invoke the quantum physic here . And I wish that there is people to understand your answer.

Comment: Nice one ! I posted below a proof that the bound is actually a minimum, using your indication to use Hermite polynomials (btw how did you get this idea ?).

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer of achille hui I will show that the lower bound
$$ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n}$$
is actually a minimum.

Let $z_j$ be the $n$ zeros of the Hermite polynomial of order n, then we have the so-called  Stieltjes sums (see http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0514028) :
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(z_k-z_j)^2} =  \frac{1}{3}(2n-(z_k)^2-2)$$
(everytime the sums have to be understood without the singular terms $1/0$).

Now define
$$ x_j := \alpha\, z_j$$
for some $\alpha >0$. The above formula gives
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(x_k-x_j)^2} =  \frac{1}{3\alpha^2}(2n-\alpha^{-2}(x_k)^2-2).$$
Notice that the $x_j$ are symetrics with respect to $x = 0$ (if $z$ is a zero of the Hermite polynomial of order $n$, then $-z$ too), we have
$$\sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n} \frac{1}{(x_i-x_j)^2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(x_k-x_j)^2}
 = \frac{n(n-1)}{3\alpha^2} - \frac{1}{6\alpha^4} \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k)^2.$$
Now still using the symmetry of the $x_j$, it is not hard to show that
$$ \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_i-x_j)^2 = n \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k)^2.$$
So one has
$$ \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_i-x_j)^2 +  \frac{1}{(x_i-x_j)^2} =  \frac{n(n-1)}{3\alpha^2} + \left(n-\frac{1 }{6\alpha^4}\right) \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k)^2.$$
Now we use another "well-known"
 formula (see [Why the sum of the squares of the roots of the $n$th Hermite polynomial is equal to $n(n-1)/2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439673/why-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-the-roots-of-the-nth-hermite-polynomial-is-equal))
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (z_k)^2 = \frac{n(n-1)}2 $$
so one has
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k)^2 = \alpha^2\frac{n(n-1)}2 $$
and
$$ \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_i-x_j)^2 +  \frac{1}{(x_i-x_j)^2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{4} \frac{2 n \alpha^4 +1}{\alpha^2}.$$
The above quantity is minimal for
$$ \alpha = (2n)^{-1/4}$$
and in this case we have
$$   \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_i-x_j)^2 +  \frac{1}{(x_i-x_j)^2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sqrt{2n} \quad \text{for $x_k = (2n)^{-1/4}  z_k$}.$$

Comment: +1 cool. (BTW, I come across Hermite polynomial when I'm doing a literature search on Calogero-Moser system and some paper claim that the equilibrium positions are proportional to the Hermite polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

Your first inequality  it's just AM-GM.

Indeed, let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+x$ and $c=a+y$.

Thus, $x>0$ and $y>0$ and 
$$\sum_{cyc}\left((a-b)^2+\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}\right)=x^2+y^2+(x-y)^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}=$$
$$=2(x^2-xy+y^2)+\frac{(x^2-xy+y^2)^2}{x^2y^2(x-y)^2}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{2(x^2-xy+y^2)^3}{x^2y^2(x-y)^2}}=$$
$$=2\sqrt{\frac{2\left((x-y)^2+2\frac{xy}{2}\right)^3}{x^2y^2(x-y)^2}}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{2\left(3\sqrt[3]{(x-y)^2\cdot\left(\frac{xy}{2}\right)^2}\right)^3}{x^2y^2(x-y)^2}}=\sqrt{54}$$

Comment: Have you an idea for the others cases dear Michael ?

Comment: @max8128 I have a proof for $n=4$. If you wish I can show the proof.

Comment: Yes if this can inspire me I would like to see that .

Comment: @max8128 My proof is very ugly and I think it does not give an inspiration.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Looks good now. 
The equality condition looks horrendous, like $x \approx 1.578, y \approx 0.882$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin the equality occurs for $(x-y)^2=\frac{xy}{2}$...

Comment: There is also the additional constraint from the first inequality that $2x^2y^2(x-y)^2 = ( x^2 - xy + y^2 ) $. Your condition easily factorizes and yields $x=2y, y = 2x$, which is satisfied in my given values. Note that $x=2, y = 1$ does not yield a minimum expression value of $ \sqrt{54}$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I think for $x=2$ and $y=1$ we get $\sqrt{54}$ in the last expression exactly.

Comment: Note that I agree with "$x=2, y=1$ satisfies the second inequality} because all we need is $x=2y$ or $y=2x$". I am interested in the equality case of the entire expression. What you are forgetting, is the additional constraint from the first inequality. 

Alternatively put, are you saying that $ 2^2 + 1^2  + (2-1)^2 + \frac{1}{2^2 } + \frac{1}{1^2 } + \frac{ 1}{ (2-1)^2 } = \sqrt{ 54 } $?

Comment: @Calvin Lin I said about last expression only. See my previous comment,

Comment: Right, so we're just talking about different things. I'm interested in the equality condition for the entire expression (which IMO looks horrendous), you're interested in the equality condition for the 2nd inequality only (which is very nice).

Comment: @Calvin Lin The equality occurs for example for $x=2y$ and for the first AM-GM. It was your mistake with $x=1,578...$ and $y=0.882...$.